# Push to multidimensional array in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array

i have a problem with push and multidimensional array.

This is my code:

```
var rows = [0, 1, 3, 5]

var content = [KUNDENNUMMER = [], NAME = []];
var r = 0;
jQuery.each( rows, function() {

    content.KUNDENNUMMER.push(jQuery("#KUNDENNUMMER_"+ rows[r]).val());    
    content.NAME.push(jQuery("#NAME_"+ rows[r]).val());
    r++;
});
```

Returns: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined(…)

Any ideas?

Comment: `content` is an array and you can't have named indicies in javascript.

Comment: Your Object syntax is not correct . `var content = {KUNDENNUMMER : [], NAME : []};`

Comment: @tracevipin, that's because this _valid_ array syntax :-)

Comment: `var content = [KUNDENNUMMER = [], NAME = []];` doesn't do what you think it does. It creates two global variables, and adds their value to `content`. These names don't have any connection to `content` after the code has been executed. `content` will be just `[[],[]]`. Though, if you'd set `KUNDENUMMER[0] = 100`, also `content[0][0]` would get the value of `100`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the following code:

```
const content = { KUNDENNUMMER: [], NAME: [] };

content.KUNDENNUMMER.push(1);
content.KUNDENNUMMER.push(2);

content.NAME.push('a');
content.NAME.push('b');

console.log(JSON.stringify(content));

console.log((content.KUNDENNUMMER[0]) + "," + (content.KUNDENNUMMER[1]));
console.log((content.NAME[0]) + "," + (content.NAME[1]));
```

The output of which is:

```
{"KUNDENNUMMER":[1,2],"NAME":["a","b"]}
1,2
a,b
```

Perhaps this is the structure you're after.